# Pass result to template depending on func.sum() value in flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm doing some calculations in my routes.py file. With the code below I can pass the results of the calculations to my template.

```
**(my routes.py)**
@app.route('/sum')
def sum():
    tups = db.session.query(Mat2.elev.label("elevnavn"), db.func.sum(Mat2.a 
    + Mat2.b + Mat2.c + Mat2.d + Mat2.e).label("csum")).group_by(Mat2.id).all()
return render_template('sum.html', tups=tups)


**(my template)**
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sum</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for i in tups %}
    <p>{{ i.csum }}</p><br>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
```

I've been trying to pass different strings to the template depending on the values of the calculations. Something like...

if the csum value is between 0 and 100 print "something"

elif the csum value us between 101 and 150 print "something else".

I can't seem to find a solution to my problem. Any tips on how it can be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqlalchemy ORM packs powerful expression APIs that can be used for queries of the kind 
 described in your question.

For your use case, the resulting query will be:

> SELECT *field1, field2, ...*
>   CASE 
>       WHEN (sum(*field1*) >= :param_1 AND sum(*field1*) <= :param_2) THEN :param_3 
>       WHEN (sum(*field1*) >= :param_4 AND sum(*field1*) <= :param_5) THEN :param_6 
>   END AS *alias* 
>   FROM *table* 
>   GROUP BY *field2*

This can be written similarly by using [`sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case) for generating `CASE` expression.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import case, and_

elevnavn = Mat2.elev.label("elevnavn")
csum = db.func.sum(Mat2.a + Mat2.b + Mat2.c + Mat2.d + Mat2.e)

from_0_to_100 = and_(csum >= 0, csum <= 100)
from_101_to_150 = and_(csum >= 101, csum <= 150)

csum_cases = case([
    (from_0_to_100, "something"),
    (from_101_to_150, "something else")
]).label("csum")

tups = db.session.query(elevnavn, csum_cases).group_by(Mat2.id).all()
```